# How to Sync InteliJ Build with Generated Ant?

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ 14, I successfully generated Ant XML from what was in the Project Structure Artifacts GUI. I can run Ant targets and have successfully modified the Ant XML. Now `Build -> Make Project` gives me pre-ant-modification results. I expected IntelliJ to use or stay in sync with the Ant XML after generating it. Is there a way to get that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to import the modifications of an Ant file into the IntelliJ IDEA project model. IntelliJ IDEA's build does not use Ant in any way, and in general the structure of Ant files is much more general than what's supported by IntelliJ's project model.

What you can do is stop using IntelliJ's Make Project action and always build your project through Ant from IntelliJ. To do this, run "Add as Ant build file" action on your generated build file, and run build actions from the Ant toolwindow. Then, in your run configurations, you can replace "Before launch: Make" with "Before launch: Run Ant target".

Comment: I rather like IntelliJ's build. I moved to Ant only to be able to zip up some files in a proprietary structure after everything is built. Is there a way to do that in IntelliJ? Or, is there some way to have "Make Project" fire off an Ant target?

Comment: You can set up an artifact in the project structure dialog. Or you can write an Ant build script that will package the results of the IntelliJ compilation as your zip file, and leave the rest of the build to IntelliJ.

Comment: I changed the build to just invoke ant post-processing to zip up the files. Perfect!